# Can you monitor changes() on a rethinkdb query with an inner join?

Tags: rethinkdb

I tried monitoring changes on a query with a join

```
r.table("presence").innerJoin(r.table('authors'), function(presence, author){
  return r.expr(author('highlights')).contains(presence('name'));
}).getField('left').changes()
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
e: Cannot call `changes` after `concat_map` in:
r.table("presence").innerJoin(r.table("authors"), function(var_115, var_116) { return var_116("highlights").contains(var_115("name")); }).getField("left").changes()
```

is that legal and which part is the part that is doing the `concat_map` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `innerJoin` is sugar syntax on top of `concat_map`. Actually, you can always use `concatMap` to solve join problem.

Unfortunately you cannot use `changes` after `concatMap`, according to https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/ruby/

We have an issue to track this, and it is probably landed in 2.3 or 2.4 as they said. https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3997

So yes, you cannot use `changes` after `join` at this moment.

However, I'm trying to go a bit further to see if I can produce something that may work. Just give it a try.

From what I understand, you have a `presence` table, your join is actually used as a filter/where `author. highlights` contains `presence.name`, then listen for change on it. How about trying to get the change first, then call `filter` later to filter out data. Like this:

```
r.table("presence")
  .changes()
  .map(function(change) {
    return change('new_val')
  })
  .filter(function(change) {
    return r.table('authors').filter(function(author) {
      return author('highlights').contains(change('name'))
    }).count().gt(0)
  })
```

Note that this query is not optimized. If it works for you, we can continue on adding index to make it run faster.

Comment: so I think that covers the case where the presence table is updated, but what if the authors.highlights embedded array is updated in real-time, that won't emit a changes event right?  If that's the case is there a standard way of modifying an existing changes watcher?  Should I just flush it or delete it in some safe way and re-create ( I don't want to say lose out on any updates while I nil out the previous changes observer and re-initialize a new one).  Is there something I should do flush and deallocate a `changes()` observer in javascript to make sure its not holding on to any resources?